# Why Does Ruby Only Permit Certain Operator Overloading

Tags: ruby, methods, operators, operator-overloading

In Ruby, like in many other OO programming languages, operators are overloadable. However, only certain character operators can be overloaded.

This list may be incomplete but, here are some of the operators that cannot be overloaded:

```
!, not, &&, and, ||, or
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Methods are overloadable, those are part of the language syntax.

Comment: As Jorg mentioned in his answer, `!` can be overridden.

Comment: how can I overide "+=" method?  and how can I add "++" method?

Answer (score 26):

["The && and || operators are not overloadable, mainly because they provide "short circuit" evaluation that cannot be reproduced with pure method calls."](http://ola-bini.blogspot.com/2007/10/operator-overloading-in-ruby.html?showComment=1191704640000#c7207705878073349200)

-- Jim Weirich

Comment: Actually, that's not a problem. Instead of translating `a && b` into `a.&&(b)`, you could translate it into `a.&& { b }`. Blocks *do* provide lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 13):

Yep. Operators are not overloadable. Only methods.

Some operators are not really. They're sugar for methods. So `5 + 5` is really `5.+(5)`, and `foo[bar] = baz` is really `foo.[]=(bar, baz)`.

Answer (score 6):

In Ruby 1.9, the `!` operator is actually also a method and can be overriden. This only leaves `&&` and `||` and their low-precedence counterparts `and` and `or`.

There's also some other "combined operators" that cannot be overriden, e.g. `a != b` is actually `!(a == b)` and `a += b` is actually `a = a+b`.

Comment: how can I overide "+=" method? and how can I add "++" method?

Comment: You can't override the `+=` method, because, as I already explained in my answer, there *is no* `+=` operator, and thus there cannot be a corresponding method. `++` is not a valid identifier, so you need to use reflection to create such a method: `define_method(:'++') do |arg| puts "Hello from #{__callee__} with #{arg}" end; __send__(:'++', 42)`.

Answer (score 2):

And let's not forget about `<<` for example:

```
string = "test"
string << "ing"
```

is the same as calling:

```
string.<<("ing")
```