# Overload ! operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload ! operator in Ruby language?

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can overload this ! in Ruby 1.9, see here http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4 , in this url they had given what are the operators, which are overloaded in Ruby

Comment: Oddly, that version of the Pickaxe was from Ruby 1.6; its claim that `!` may be overridden is not valid for Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Ruby 1.9 `!` is a method and can be overridden.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92862/why-does-ruby-only-permit-certain-operator-overloading/109347#109347)